# setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled() error: non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

I have two parts of codes. One has the error, but the other doesn't.

```
ActionBar theActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if (theActionBar != null) {
    // error: non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context
    ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

.

Does anyone happen to know how to explain this?

Comment: `ActionBar.set` compared to `theActionBar.set`... Use the actual instance variable, not the class

Comment: That was my bad. Didn't notice the typo. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error says it all. Just change this line:

```
ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

to

```
theActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

or just change your code to look like this:

```
if(getSupportActionBar() != null)
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: That was my bad. Didn't notice the typo. Thanks a lot.